# How to update and insert into db with @transactional on db query

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I have one table warehouse_item_mapping
having columns - warehouseId, itemId, stockQuantity

```
   warehouse_id        item_id        stock_quantity
    1                   123              10
    1                   234              20
    1                   345              30
```

This table is being used as inventory management as maintaining current stock of items in warehouse.

Now if new stock has come with some items including new items with current stock quantity.

Like

```
 1    123       50
 1    234       50
 1    678       50 (new item)
```

I have to update the stock quantity in table as sum of existing quantity and current stock quantity. And if mapping not found in table then insert that new mapping.

For this case table should be updated as

```
   warehouse_id        item_id        stock_quantity
    1                   123              60
    1                   234              70
    1                   345              30 
    1                   678              50
```

How to do this in single query.

Follow up question in this is

```
   If someone used the current stock from table in between get and update query then how to maintain lock or transactional for whole flow.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/) is what you need. In combination with pre selected stock_quantity. You need to make item_id [PRIMARY KEY](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-primary-key/).

Now of course you will be using one SELECT and one INSERT INTO statement with PHP ( i guess) variables.

```
SELECT @stock_quantity:=stock_quantity FROM warehouse_item_mapping WHERE item_id=123;

INSERT INTO warehouse_item_mapping (warehouse_id, item_id, stock_quantity) 
VALUES (1, 123, 50) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE warehouse_id=1, stock_quantity=@stock_quantity+50;
```

Working example: [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pbow3Pw4vaDMba5FArGqxq/0)

RESULT:

```
Results
Query #1 Execution time: 0ms
warehouse_id    item_id     stock_quantity
1   123     60
1   234     70
1   345     30
1   678     50
```

SO lats say you are using PHP:

```
    PHP:
    '$item_id' // your new OR old inserting item id.
    '$warehouse_id'
    '$stock_quantity' // Your NEW stock number.

START TRANSACTION;

SELECT @stock_quantity:=stock_quantity 
FROM warehouse_item_mapping WHERE item_id='$item_id';

INSERT INTO warehouse_item_mapping (warehouse_id, item_id, stock_quantity) 
VALUES ('$warehouse_id', '$item_id', '$stock_quantity') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE warehouse_id='$warehouse_id', stock_quantity=@stock_quantity+'$stock_quantity';

COMMIT;
```

This will try to insert a value only if PRIMARY KEY item-id doesn't exists. If it does it will update other two fields.

**EDIT:**

I think you are confused what [@transaction is, read about it here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx).
Above is example of one as you asked for it but this can also be done in one query as mentioned in comment. Example:

```
INSERT INTO warehouse_item_mapping (warehouse_id, item_id, stock_quantity) 
VALUES (1, 123, 50) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
warehouse_id=1, stock_quantity=stock_quantity+50;
```

[Working Fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eEfPn9fAZVwhLMt6AdMtBH/0)

PHP:

```
INSERT INTO warehouse_item_mapping (warehouse_id, item_id, stock_quantity) 
VALUES ('$warehouse_id', '$item_id', '$stock_quantity') ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE warehouse_id='$warehouse_id', stock_quantity=stock_quantity+'$stock_quantity';
```

Comment: Probably better to have `(warehouse_id, item_id)` as the primary key. Also you don't need an additional query for `stock_quantity`.

Comment: Yeah i have combination of both as primary key. But can we do it in one query like select and update/insert if not found  both in one query. So that i can make @transaction on whole operation. As its stock updation. No one will be able to change the stock quantity at that time

Comment: I have used one query. Will it run fine. `update WarehouseItemMappingEntity wme set wme.stockQuantity = wme.stockQuantity + :currentStock where wme.warehouseId = :warehouseId  and wme.itemId = :itemId` This query is in hibernate. @v.ladynev